# Wifi problem on 12.04.5

Tags: wireless

Hi I have a lenovo laptop and just install Ubuntu 12.04.5, my wifi card doesn’t work. I have internet connection only with a wifi stick usb. What can I do?
Thank you and sorry for my English

Comment: Please add output of "lspci -knn | grep Net -A2" and "rfkill list" to your question.

Comment: Why did you not install Ubuntu **14.04.2** LTS? *It may already support this laptop's WiFi chipset.*

Comment: I have install 15.10 and its ok now!